# How can I create a QList object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I have imported the below 2 libraries:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

I am trying to create a QList object as below:

```
self.myList = QList()
```

I am getting an error:

```
NameError: global name 'QList' is not defined
```

QList being under QtCore, I expect it to work.

Please suggest how to correct it.

Comment: You sure about QList? on http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html they list only QListView, QListWidget and QListWidgetItem (+ things like QTextList…) but no QList

Comment: yes, please see [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html)

Comment: QList is available in C++ as convenient container - in pyqt you should use native containers.

Comment: oh okay..please suggest what should I use in pyqt, similar to QList()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QList` class is a template class that provides lists. available in C++ only.
But in python, it have `python list` data-type ready to used.
If you want to use behavior like list you can use  `python list` similar `QList`.

I have reference useful tutorials point for this. please read this to implement `python list`;

**Python Lists** : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

And, Official Python Lists reference;

**Data Structures** : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

---

Regards,

Comment: Python list cannot be serialized with [PyQt QDataStream](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatastream.html), while [Qt QList can be serialized](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#reading-and-writing-qt-collection-classes) with C++. QList cannot be replaced by Python list without precautions, e.g. when porting [this C++ example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html#tablemodel-class-definition). Private variable `QList<Contact> contacts` is serialized in `AddressWidget::writeToFile()`. This C++ method requires some adjustments when ported to Python.