# PyQt: Obtain all pixels inside QPolygon

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt 5, is there a way to obtain all pixel positions that would be modified by a call to `QPainter.drawPolygon` for a `QPainter` object constructed with some `QImage` as an argument without actually drawing the polygon? Ideally I would like to obtain separate sets of pixel positions for the polygon's border and for all pixels inside the polygon.

Comment: [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html).

Comment: How would that work? I can see how I would obtain such an object but not how I could extract all pixels within it.

Comment: Use the `contains()` and `intersects()` methods.

Comment: Does that mean I have to iterate through all pixels inside a bounding rectangle and call `contains` on every one? That does not seem very efficient to me. In that case, why would I need the intermediate `QPainterPath` at all?

Comment: I haver no idea, since your question is so light on details. Why can't you just create a `QPolygon` and iterate over its points?

Comment: That is not possible, is it (explicitely iterating over all points in a `QPolygon`)?. I was thinking that the `drawPolygon` method might internally use some smart algorithm to avoid iterating over all points in a bounding rectangle and that I could utilize that for other purposes than drawing the polygon. I don't think there is anything more specific to it.

Comment: Well, [QPolygon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolygon.html#) is a subclass of `QVector`. so I don't see why you can't iterate over it. In fact, it's hard to see what the purpose of `QPolygon` would be if it didn't provide that functionality.

Comment: Sure you can, but that only yields the polygon's corners.

Comment: But why do you need *every point* in advance? What ***specifically*** are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Just like [@ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) said, QPolygon is a subclass of QVector (that is, a QList). However, in [Pyqt this is a Python array and not a QList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159732/how-can-i-create-a-qlist-object). I got runtime errors when trying to iterate over this list, because it was inside the QPolygon object and there was no getter. In this case, in PyQt the solution is not very efficient. You need to iterate over each pixel of the image, creating a QPoint with pixel coordinates and checking if the QPolygon contains this point through the ***containsPoint*** method. There aren't many implementation details, but consider the following code snippet.

```
array_qpoints = [] # this array will have all the QPoints
polygon = QPolygon([
        QPoint(140,234),
        QPoint(126,362),
        QPoint(282,409),
        QPoint(307,273),
        QPoint(307,233),
])

# let's consider a 640x480 image
for x in range(640):
   for y in range(480):
      point = QPoint(x, y)
      if polygon.containsPoint(point, Qt.FillRule.OddEvenFill):
         array_qpoints.append(point)
```

You can get the coordinates of each pixel by calling the x() and y() methods for each element in array_qpoints.

```
for point in array_qpoints:
   x = point.x()
   y = point.y()
   # do what you want with the information
```

I'm posting this answer for others who visit this question and are looking for a solution by code. Since it's been several years, if you've found a better solution, please post :)